# Store the separate quantity for both website products in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I've 2 website in magento.

I want to store the separate quantity of product for each web site.

Example:

Website 1:

Product SKU : ABC-123

Qty: 10

Price: 23

Website 2:

Product SKU : ABC-123

Qty: 25

Price: 53

How can access the quantity 10 for website1 & quantity 25 for website2.

Please help me on this issue

Comment: I personally use the extension embedded erp that manages those kind of needs. If you can't afford to buy it, you might have to code it yourself with a stock management per website which will be more complicated. see more here https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/embedded-erp-2-9-5.html

Comment: thanks. I'll make my custom extension

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, magento doesn't support separate inventories. Quantity in stock is set **globally** and there is no way to make it website, store or view based by magento default means. However, this could be resolved by a custom extension that you could find at magento connect or write one yourself. 
I did have the same problem and eventually wrote my own custom extension.